# Prime number in python, prog not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

After I run this, it doesn't print anything:

```
for n in range(2,100):
     for x in range(2,n):
        if n%x == 0:
         break
        else:
          if n==x:
           print n,'is a prime number'
```

Comment: You can use additional variable to put the result of n%x==0

Comment: Don't tag the question as Python 3 when it obviously isn't.

Comment: FYI, it's only necessary for the inner loop to iterate over `range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)))` to determine if `n` is prime. The reason is this: if some integer `a` larger than `sqrt(n)` divides `n`, then `n / a` is equal to some integer `b`. The integer `b` must *also* divide `n`, since `a * b = n`. Because `a` is larger than `sqrt(n)`, `b` must be less than `sqrt(n)` and it will be found before `x` reaches `sqrt(n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if n==x` will never be true, because the inner loop only runs for values of `x` from `2` to `n-1`.

If you need to check that the inner loop ran to completion, use `else` after the `for` itself. This will execute the `else` if `break` hasn't been performed:

```
for n in range(2,100):
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n%x == 0:
             break
    else:
        print n,'is a prime number'
```

A more Pythonic way to do this is by using `all` with a generator expression:

```
for n in range(2,100):
    if all(n%x != 0 for x in range(2,n)):
        print n,'is a prime number'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic dictates this - anything with a remainder of 0 will break out of the loop, and any value modulo itself will be `0`, so your `else` block will never be reached where the contained `if` will be run.

Comment: suppose 3%3 so its modulo equals to 0 so when it break out else part will work and in that n==x mean 3==3 and print n mean print 3. but its doesn't print even one word.

Comment: `break` will break out of your `for` loop - so the `else` part will never get run, as it is within the loop.